# sIFR seems to be loading correctly but not displaying text

Tags: sifr

I'm Using sIFR 3r436, and although I believe everything is set up correctly, and my console shows that the .swf font file is loading correctly, the HTML type is hidden but the sIFR type is not displaying. Below is a link to the site in question:

[Schaffer's Website](http://www.schaffers.com)

Below is a link to a test site that uses exactly the same sifr-config.js, sifr.js, css, and swf files. And it works. The main difference between the two is the server that they are running on.

[Schaffer's Test Site](http://www.designmeasure.com/clients/schaffers/website/)

I'm hoping that maybe somebody can see a problem that I'm unable to. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

The server gives a 403 forbidden for the Flash movie – in other words, it does not load.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. How did you determine that a 403 forbidden is occuring? My error console in Safari doesn't indicate any problem loading gil.swf. Are there any obvious reasons why a 403 might be occuring when sIFR tries to load an swf?

Comment: I tried to open the SWF directly. Wouldn't know why the server refuses to show the file.